# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' and Unable to merge dex

Tags: android, dependencies, dex

When I build my app, I got this error .

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>   More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'

I don't know how to solve this error. I googled this for hours but it still doesn't work

My project gradle:

```
     // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common
     to all sub-projects/modules.

     buildscript {

         repositories {
             google()
             jcenter()
         }
         dependencies {
             classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


             // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
             // in the individual module build.gradle files
         } }

     allprojects {
         repositories {
             google()
             jcenter()
         } }

     task clean(type: Delete) {
         delete rootProject.buildDir 
    }
```

My app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.example.tingyu.receivedatajson"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('src/main/java/com/example/tingyu/receivedatajson/httpclient-4.5.jar')
    implementation files('src/main/java/com/example/tingyu/receivedatajson/httpclient-win-4.5.jar')
    implementation files('src/main/java/com/example/tingyu/receivedatajson/httpcore-4.4.1.jar')
    implementation files('src/main/java/com/example/tingyu/receivedatajson/json-simple-1.1.jar')
    implementation files('src/main/java/com/example/tingyu/receivedatajson/utils-json-common-3.0.0.jar')
    implementation files('src/main/java/com/example/tingyu/receivedatajson/utils-json-handler-2.0.0.jar')
    implementation files('src/main/java/com/example/tingyu/receivedatajson/org.osgi.foundation-1.0.0.jar')
    implementation files('src/main/java/com/example/tingyu/receivedatajson/java-json.jar')
    implementation files('src/main/java/com/example/tingyu/receivedatajson/org.json.jar')
    implementation files('src/main/java/com/example/tingyu/receivedatajson/org.json.simple-0.3-incubating-sources.jar')
    implementation files('src/main/java/com/example/tingyu/receivedatajson/commons-lang-2.1.jar')
    implementation files('src/main/java/com/example/tingyu/receivedatajson/apache-collections-commons-collections-3.1.jar')
    implementation files('src/main/java/com/example/tingyu/receivedatajson/ezmorph-1.0.3.jar')
    implementation files('src/main/java/com/example/tingyu/receivedatajson/jsonplugin-0.33.jar')
    implementation files('src/main/java/com/example/tingyu/receivedatajson/json-lib-2.1-jdk15.jar')
    implementation files('src/main/java/com/example/tingyu/receivedatajson/commons-beanutils-core-1.7.0.jar')
}
```

I try this:

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
```

then got error :

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: execute this command in your project root directory:`gradlew --stacktrace assemble` and post your error stack.

Answer (score 4):

put this in you build.gradle .

then Clean and rebuild project

```
android{
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'

   }
}
```

Comment: I tried but it display :

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: Have you tried disabling/enabling Instant Run or add multidex enabled in android{}